# How to set the default value of mongoose field to the number of existing entries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to set the default value for a field in a mongoose schema to the number of entries which are already existing in the DB.

The first entry to be created would have the value `0` for this field, the second entry should have the value `1` etc.

**Background**: it should be some kind of sorting index, which should be changeable by the user, but defaults to the order of creation of the entries. Thus, it should be a unique, sequential number.

This is how my mongoose Schema looks so far:

```
const CategorySchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  sorting: { type: Number, index: { unique: true }, default: ##number_of_existing_entries### },
  creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

Can anybody please help me how to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: You can't do this kind of operation at an ORM level like Mongoose itself, but wut you can do is improvement this feature in a JavaScript level

Comment: @FelixFong: Sure, that would be the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I know that's an old question, but in case you've found it in google like me...

Half of the solution:

```
const CategorySchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    sorting: { 
        type: Number, 
        index: { unique: true }, 
        default: function() {
            const collection = this.parent().categories;
            return (collection) ? collection.length : 0;
        }
    },
    creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

The other half would be to get the collection name automatically